# How to create a VS 2015 project for Firefox

Tags: visual-studio, firefox

I have just downloaded and set up the Firefox code repo. I was wondering how can I make a Visual Studio 2015 project from the code so that I can use its GUI and the debugger.

Comment: As i think it depends on the language you use Whether if it is C# then go and create a C# Project if not then go for VB project and that is all

Comment: I found these links useful
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687388
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_Mozilla_on_Windows_FAQ